# How to delete files from google drive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I tried using the following code to delete files from google drive using python. But it is not working as the files are not getting cleared from drive after running this. uploading/downloading is getting done but deletion has this problem. I've been stuck at this point for a while and finding it hard to figure out.

```
def delete_file(service, file_id):
    service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()
```

The scope I'm using here is

```
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
```

Comment: did you empty the trash after deleting it?

Comment: When I saw your script, it seems that you use the method of "Files: delete". In this case, the file can be permanently deleted. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete) I think that when the correct values of `service` and `file_id` are given to `service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()`, the file of `file_id` is permanently deleted. So in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? For example, your file is in the shared drive?

Comment: @Guy Nachshon Thanks a lot! it got deleted after clearing the trash. I do not understand however why delete action alone does not suffice for this.

Comment: @Tanaike It is not a shared drive. the problem seemed to be with clearing the trash as Guy Nachshon pointed out.

Comment: @Viv that's great! accept my answer below so it would be easier for future people to find :)

Comment: @I do not know what you mean by accepting the answer. I'm new to this platform.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding the answer here if someone will encounter this in the future:

You should clear the trash after deleting the file:

```
 service.files().emptyTrash().execute()
```